# Customer registration form - subscription checkbox

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, checkbox

So on my customer account registration form: `domain.com/customer/account/create/` I would like to set the newsletter subscription checkbox, so it is already checked.

So I have looked in the `register.phtml` code `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml` and at lines 60 to 76 it has this code:

Added code to make registration box have the tick box automatically ticked

```
<?php
$checked = true;
if($this->getFormData()->getEmail()) {
if(!$this->getFormData()->getIsSubscribed()) {
    $checked = true;
    }
}   
?>
```

and

```
<li class="control">
  <div class="input-box">
   /* added with the additional code above */
   <input type="checkbox" name="is_subscribed" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign Up for Newsletter') ?>" value="1" id="is_subscribed" checked="checked" class="checkbox" />
...
```

It looks as though this should do what I want but on my live site, it isn't working. I even took out the /* text */ as I thought this may have an effect but it had no effect.

Any suggestions are most welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change any code in the **base** folder, since this contains Magento original files that will be used as a "backup" for your website. Also, if you update your Magento version, this "core" files will be replaced.

If you are using a custom theme, go to the folder:

```
app/design/frontend/[theme_company]/[theme_name]/template/customer/form/register.phtml
```

If you don't have any installed theme, the folder should be:

```
app/design/frontend/default/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
```

Make the changes in one of these files and should work fine. Don't forget to undo all changes in the **base** folder that you made. Also, you may need to **clear the cache** to see the changes.

Comment: Thank you @Bruno Monteiro for your response. 

I've undone the changes I made and now copied the register.phtml file to my custom (Ultimo theme) folder using the correct hierarchy. But when I try and change the code, it doesn't seem to change my live site. Even when I change the Base file it doesn't change either, so I am a bit stuck.

Do you know what changes I need to make so I can make the checkbox already ticked by default?

Comment: I turned on template path hints and where my checkbox is located on my customer/create page, it looks like the file is brought in from frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml but I've never come across the <strong>'persistent'</strong> folder in my Magento directory. Can you shed any more light on this please? Many thanks.

Comment: Are you cleaning the cache? You can do that manually going in the folder `var/cache` and delete everything there.

Comment: Also, is your theme set to be used in your admin panel? Magento will get the files from your **theme folder** (if you are using the theme), if not will get from the **default** (not the base) folder. Magento just go to the **base** folder when all other options fail for any reason. If you are using a development environment or if is OK to make some changes, I would completely remove the checkbox field, clear the cache and go to the page again. This way you can confirm if you are updating the right file.

Comment: Hi @Bruno Monteiro, your comments helped me alot. I had another look through my folder structure and found the correct register.phtml file. It was inside a folder called 'persistent' (which I didn't see first time I looked), this was found in the base folder. 
Next I duplicated the folder structure to my theme folder and from there I managed to make the checkbox set to a default of ticked. 

Thanks again for your help! I will mark this post as solved. =)

Comment: That's great! Glad you solved your problem...